# X-editable , change from popup to inline, responsively

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I'm using **X-Editable** to do inline edits of my data - http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html

This all works fine - but now I want to make it so it responds a bit better on smaller screens. Anything down to 600px width looks fine using "**inline**". However, as soon as you get below that - it starts moving the other columns around. The only way to resolve this, is to change it from "**inline**" to "**popup**". I've come up with:

```
$(document).ready( function() { 

    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
        console.log("Changing to popup");
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
    }

    $('.text-editor-num').editable( {
        type: 'number',
        url: '/cgi-bin/links/booking/admin.cgi',
        params: { action: "reservation_edit_item" }
    }); 

    $(window).resize(function() { 
        if ($(window).width() < 600) {
            console.log("Changing to popup");
            $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
        } else {
            console.log("Changing to inline");
            $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
        }
    });

});
```

The initial load part (lines 3 to 8) work fine. However, if you resize the window (i.e on a mobile device, changing from portrait to landscape), this messes it up. I was trying to get around this using:

```
    $(window).resize(function() { 
        if ($(window).width() < 600) {
            console.log("Changing to popup");
            $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
        } else {
            console.log("Changing to inline");
            $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
        }
    });
```

..which would then update the way we show the X-editable bits. However, is just keeps the original setting. From what I'm gathering, I need to re-initalize the `editable()` object - but I'm unsure how to do this. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

I've also tried this kind of approach too:

```
  $('.text-editor-num').editable('option','mode','popup');
```

... but to no avail

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the x-editable first.
Change you resize function to:

```
 $(window).resize(function() { 
    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
        console.log("Changing to popup");
        $('.text-editor-num').editable('destroy');
        $('.text-editor-num').editable({
            mode: 'popup',
        });
    } else {
        console.log("Changing to inline");
        $('.text-editor-num').editable('destroy');
        $('.text-editor-num').editable({
            mode: 'inline',
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Aaaah - that did it! The `destroy` was the bit I was missing. Thanks!